# Spring data redis repository doesn't support collection query?

Tags: java, spring-data-redis

We can do 'findByXXsIn' in spring data JPA, but it seems that I failed to do this in spring data Redis, is there an alternative to do this?

I tagged an object, and store the relation in `Redis(tagId,targetId,targetType)`.

```
public interface TagRelationRepository {
    Page<TagRelation> findTagRelationByTagIdIn(List<String> tagIds,Pageable page);
    Page<TagRelation> findTagRelationByTargetType(TagTargetType targetType,Pageable page);
    List<TagRelation> findByTargetIdInAndTargetType(List<Long> targetIds,TagTargetType targetType); 
}
```

It's many to many relationship, I want to get the relations by tagIds but just failed.

Answer (score 2):

Currently only simple finder methods with the keywords `Is` or `Equals` as well as combinations of those using `And` / `Or` are supported.
Please refer to *Table 5. Supported keywords* in the [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.queries) for *Queries and Query Methods*.